# Choosing emitter resistor

Tags: transistors, igbt

I`m not sure if this is the right place to ask but: I have fried ignition circiut which is based on IGBT. I narrowed that the transistor is gone along with the emitter resistor. The datasheet for the IGBT does not show that resistor in place therefore I am having difficulty choosing the right size. I hope someone can help. Datasheet https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ISL9V3040P3-D.PDF
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is an V8 electronic distributor. The trace goes to the IC, but the marking on the IC has been removed, I guess to protect the manufacturers from copying hence a wide issue. I have attached the Picture of the this circuit. There no similar circuit on the board to check/copy and I don't have access to anything similar.

Comment: Is there repeated circuitry that is similar on the PCB or do you have access to another similar product?  You may still have trouble measuring it, typical values are tens of m\$\Omega\$.

Comment: It is a low value sense resistor used to measure current. If it is fried then probably so are other parts connected to it. The SOT23-5 part (op amp?) below the IGBT does not look healthy.

Comment: How low? Is I put 2 ohm? Good enough? Im preaty sure I saw something like 020x on it before the numbers gone.

Answer (score 1):

In a car ignition application, the IGBT would be switching the ignition coil current which would be expected to reach several Amps.

This current flows through the resistor as well so the voltage across the resistor gives a measure of the current flowing through the coil.

The trace from that resistor to the IC to the left of the resistor is probably used to sense the current flowing through the IGBT (and coil).

Since the resistor looks to be something like a 1210 size it's maximum dissipation will be limited to maybe 250mW. The maximum voltage across the resistor with say 5A peak current would probably be limited to 50-100mV  to avoid exceeding that value. If it was 50mV this would imply a resistor value of 10 milliohms.

A short across the coil would cause excessive current to flow through the resistor which could have been the reason for the failure.

Note the large number of vias just beside the resistor - they are probably to get good thermal (as well as electrical) conductivity to spread the heat dissipated by the resistor.